# Google Stackdriver logging: write_log_entries, what's inside the array?

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to figure out the data structure to use for [this example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/logging#using-the-api) from google documentation and [this example](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/logging/index.html?highlight=write_log_entries).

```
from google.cloud import logging_v2

client = logging_v2.LoggingServiceV2Client()
entries = []
response = client.write_log_entries(entries)
```

How do I format the content of the `entries` array?
And how to include a specific timestamp element, instead of a default time-of-collection timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

Example entry. You can expand on this with your custom changes such as timestamp.

```
{
    "logName": "projects/development/logs/my-test-log",
    "resource": {"type": "global"},
    "severity": "WARNING", 
    "textPayload": "Test entry"
}
```

These links documents the fields for the LogEntry, which is an object (Python dictionary).

Note that some of the fields are themselves objects:

[LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rpc/google.logging.v2#google.logging.v2.LogEntry)

[LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry)

```
{
  "logName": string,
  "resource": {
    object(MonitoredResource)
  },
  "timestamp": string,
  "receiveTimestamp": string,
  "severity": enum(LogSeverity),
  "insertId": string,
  "httpRequest": {
    object(HttpRequest)
  },
  "labels": {
    string: string,
    ...
  },
  "metadata": {
    object(MonitoredResourceMetadata)
  },
  "operation": {
    object(LogEntryOperation)
  },
  "trace": string,
  "spanId": string,
  "traceSampled": boolean,
  "sourceLocation": {
    object(LogEntrySourceLocation)
  },

  // Union field payload can be only one of the following:
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": string,
    field1: ...,
    ...
  },
  "textPayload": string,
  "jsonPayload": {
    object
  }
  // End of list of possible types for union field payload.
}
```

This link documents the timestamp:

[Timestamp](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Timestamp)

The string format of the timestamp looks like this (Gregorian Calendar):

```
Range is from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z
```

Comment: Thank you for the links, I was not able to make use of this information without a concrete (working) python sdk example.

Comment: The first part of my answer shows you the exact data structure to use in your example. All you have to do is change the project in `logName`.

Answer (score 2):

This can either be [`LogEntry`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/logging/google/cloud/logging_v2/proto/log_entry.proto#L37) objects or a dict (with the same fields as LogEntry). The latter is a bit easier. Typical use would be:

```
from google.cloud import logging_v2

client = logging_v2.LoggingServiceV2Client()
# This defines what object is emitting the logs. See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list for a list of options
res = {"type": "gce_instance",
       "labels": {
          "zone": "us-central1-a",
          "instance_id": "1235"}}
entries = []

# Add a plain text log entry
logEntry = {"text_payload": "abc YOUR MESSAGE BLAH"}
entries.append(logEntry)

# Add a structured log entry (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging)
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct
s = Struct()
s["key"] = ["value1","value2"]
logEntry = {"json_payload": s}
entries.append(logEntry)

# write a batch of logs to Stackdriver.
response = client.write_log_entries(entries,
                                    log_name='projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/[LOG_ID]',
                                    resource=res)
```

I can't find formatted docs for write_log_entry, but you can see details in the [`code comments`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/logging/google/cloud/logging_v2/gapic/logging_service_v2_client.py#L286).

LogEntry's rpc fields description: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rpc/google.logging.v2#google.logging.v2.LogEntry
Do not mix it with LogEntry's rest fields: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry

Comment: I wish it worked: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test/dummy_test_1.py", line 18, in <module>
    response = client.write_log_entries(entries, resource=res)
  File "/home/vk2167/sedna-alerts-poc/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/gapic/logging_service_v2_client.py", line 396, in write_log_entries
    dry_run=dry_run,
ValueError: Protocol message Struct has no "any" field.

Comment: I think I have the "json_payload" value incorrect. using text_payloads without json_payloads works as in my sample.

Comment: google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Logs from projects are not supported

Comment: That's really weird. Running that exact code (with the [PROJECT_ID] and [LOG_ID] replaced with actual ids, and without the json_payload) on cloud shell works perfectly for me. Do you have a different resource? have you added other fields to the log entry?

Comment: Also are you creating the LoggingServiceV2Client a different way, or doing it somewhere with no authorization or an unusual authorization environment?

Comment: from google.cloud import logging_v2

client = logging_v2.LoggingServiceV2Client()
res = {"type": "gce_instance",
       "labels": {
          "zone": "us-central1-a",
          "instance_id": "1235"}}
entries = []


logEntry = {"text_payload": "abc YOUR MESSAGE BLAH"}
entries.append(logEntry)

logEntry = {"text_payload": '{"any":["json","object"]}'}
entries.append(logEntry)


response = client.write_log_entries(entries, log_name=' projects/ema-devops-dev/logs/1235', resource=res)

Comment: The error is because you have a space before "projects" in the log_name. You should replace `' projects/...` with `'projects/`.